Reference Request: Vertex Enumeration Algorithms That Finds All Integer Points in a Polytope
For fun, I explored vertex enumeration algorithms for linear programs to find all feasible extreme points in a polytope. Naturally, I asked, "Do there exist algorithms that solve for all integer points within a polytope?", but I found only two sources that discuss this topic: this paper and this CS StackExchange question. Thus, there doesn't seem to be much research on this topic. Does there exist more papers or lectures on this topic?
Currently, I'm working on a Branch & Bound algorithm that only fathoms when it reaches infeasible solutions (in that it uniquely branches on integer solutions to find neighboring integer solutions), but I would like more resources that discuss existing algorithms that solve for all integer points such that while exploring and implementing other approaches, it can assist/improve the Branch & Cut approach I'm trying to implement.

You might want to look at the answers to this question: How to find all vertices of a polyhedron.

Is the middle branch really $n-1$ separate branches?  Also, how do you enforce $\not=$?

it is n-1 branches, as you'd have check every adjacent integer that may have the same values, and you just linearize it like you would with Big-M via https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1517850/1105283

thankfully in implementation, CPLEX already has a method of handling $\neq$

I recommend explicitly expanding the tree plot to $n-1$ branches because what you have now means something else.

I actually take that back, we are enumerating every variable, fixing them, and branching n-1 times on it, so n(n-1) branches @RobPratt

For a given node, don't you branch with respect to a single $x_i^*$?  If not, you would have a trivial tree with only two levels.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
